# 401 Error When Making Basic Authenticated API Calls to X2CRM

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication, http-error-401.2

- We are encountering a 401 error when making basic authenticated API calls to the X2CRM endpoints (`index.php/api2/Contacts`).
- Unauthenticated API calls to other X2CRM VoIP endpoints are successful without issue,
- And basic authentication works on a test page in the same directory using the same PHP-FPM pool.

We have confirmed that the credentials are stored in the database and accessible.

What could be causing this issue with basic authenticated API calls to X2CRM endpoints and how can it be resolved?

Comment: 1.) CORS issue: Some browser may block the request with 401 if the server isn't configured to allow cross-origin requests. Make sure the server is configured to allow cross-origin requests for the X2CRM API. 2.) Firewall issue: If you make a request from a different machine to the server, verify the firewall on the server allows incoming requests on the appropriate ports from it/its subnet 3.) Check log files of X2CRM and IIS, those may provide more information about the error.